# Why is Windows 10 freezing for a second everytime the background changes?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, battery, troubleshooting

I have my Windows 10 laptop set to change my desktop background every minute by using the built-in Windows feature to set it to a slideshow of a folder. It also changes the accent color accordingly. However, I've noticed that this also freezes my computer every single time it changes. The background will change, the computer will freeze for a full three seconds, and then the accent color will change.

I have a pretty powerful laptop. It has an integrated Intel HD Graphics 630 and a discrete Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050. The backgrounds are all reasonable sizes and stored on an SSD. This shouldn't be happening, and after almost seven months it's getting *really* old. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug with the Intel and Nvidia graphics drivers switching between the GPUs, as Nvidia Optimus powers off the Nvidia GPU to save power. [Intel is working on a fix and expects to have it out by April,](https://communities.intel.com/message/523340#523340) but no sure-fire fix is currently available to fix this bug.

Obviously, you can circumvent this issue by just disabling the automatic accent color until a fix is released. This can be done by going to Settings > Personalization > Color > Automatically pick an accent color from my background.

There are other solutions that might work, but none guaranteed and without their downsides. Depending on your GPUs, you may be able to download older drivers, although these may not work, especially given how new your GPUs are. They may also cause compatibility issues with other things, especially if you want to play newer games with your graphics card.

Another possible option is to install [TrayPwrD3](https://github.com/jobeid/TrayPwrD3). This will keep your discrete GPU permanently powered on. It did not work for me, but it may for others.

Comment: Can confirm that this issue still exists today. Huge thanks for pointing out the solution.

Comment: Can confirm that this issue still exists today.

Comment: Aaand today. This is going to get fixed eventually, right?

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm not switching graphics I'm on a desktop.

Comment: Also still seeing this problem every time the background changes on a desktop with Intel CPU and Nvidia GPU. I think the OP should consider un-marking this as an answer because it's not the solution to the issue for everyone.